# How to create FULLTEXT index on multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, database

I am running the following query on `tbl_query`

```
select * from tbl_query q where match(q.query_desc,q.query_desc_details) against ('test1' WITH QUERY EXPANSION);
```

It's giving an error

```
16:46:22    select * from tbl_query q where match(q.query_desc,q.query_desc_details) against ('test1' WITH QUERY EXPANSION) LIMIT 0, 1000   Error Code: 1191. Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list    0.078 sec
```

My table is like this

```
 CREATE TABLE `tbl_query` (
  `query_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `query_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `query_desc_details` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`query_id`),
  KEY `QUERY_DESC` (`query_desc`(333)) USING BTREE,
  KEY `QUERY_DESC_DETAILS` (`query_desc_details`(333)) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In database full text words boundaries are like

```
ft_max_word_len=    84
ft_min_word_len=    4
```

I am searching against two column.
So my question is how to create the full text index for the table?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Fulltext with `2` columns you create like this

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_query
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `FullText` 
(`query_desc` ASC, `query_desc_details` ASC);
```

Comment: What does ASC do?

Comment: @SupunKavinda 'ASC' indexes in ascending order whereas 'DESC' does it in descending

Comment: How do you use the 'FullText' index. I tried and it keeps saying Error 1054 Unknown column 'FullText'

Answer (score 27):

```
ALTER TABLE `TableName`
    ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `IndexName` (`ColumnName`);
```

Answer (score 16):

This creates the index. This should work.

```
ALTER TABLE `TableName` ADD FULLTEXT index_name(column1, column2);
```

Comment: I added the index but it's showing the same error. Something else need to be done?

Comment: nope it should work. Check once useing desc if it is there. Try restarting the mysql once. But this should work.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tbl_query ADD FULLTEXT index_name(query_desc,query_desc_details);` for 2 columns.

Comment: @KayNelson Does not seem to work when the table has some content already and but when you create a fresh table it works. But is there as way to make it work on tables that is already has quite a bit of data ? I am using 10.1.21-MariaDB

Answer (score 2):

Add the Index

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FULLTEXT index_name(column1, column2);
```

To get the search result

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH(column1, column2)
AGAINST('search string' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

To drop the index

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP INDEX index_name;
```