# Mysql select where contains

Tags: php, mysql

I have a social networking site which I am in the process of constructing. Users can follow each other and it adds their name to a list of followers. I need to scan that list for the session username cookie to choose which statuses (posts) to display. In my sql recordset, I have the code:

```
SELECT *
FROM statuses
WHERE followedby CONTAINS '". $_SESSION['MM_Username']."'
```

But this just brings up error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONTAINS 'Usernamecookie'' at line 1

Comment: Can you add the full line of code? It might be a problem with the quotation marks.

Comment: CONTAINS is Full Text Search (FTS) syntax, and the key word is supported on both SQL Server and Oracle (though different supporting syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM statuses
WHERE followedby LIKE '%". $_SESSION['MM_Username']."%'
```

LIKE clause is used for string matching.

Answer (score 1):

Others have correctly answered this question already, but I just want to add the meaning of `contains` in MySQL:

> MySQL only recognizes the CONTAINS SQL function when dealing with
>   spatial data. It requires two graphics objects as arguments, and
>   returns a 1 or 0 depending on if the first object completely contains
>   the second. Designed as an implementation of the OpenGIS framework,
>   the MySQL CONTAINS function does not work on ordinary strings, and
>   will produce an error if you try it. MySQL only recognizes the LIKE
>   and STRCMP functions when dealing with string of information.

So in your case, you want to use `like`.

References:

- https://blog.udemy.com/sql-contains/
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM statuses
WHERE followedby LIKE '%{$MM_Username}%' 
");
```

Put the `MM_Username` in its own var. Nicer code ;)
Remember to enable index for FollowedBy if your table grows.

Read more about how to enable fulltext indexes [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551560/how-to-create-fulltext-index-on-some-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Contains use `LIKE`.